# Intellij IDEA java code formatting: If right parenthesis at wrong indentation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have an if block with multiple lines in the expression.  Everywhere else where there is a close parenthesis, it is aligned with the start of the line with the open parenthesis except for "if" expressions.  For if expressions, it is using the continuation indent value of 8 added to the base indentation of 8 for the "if" line.

[image: Indentation should be at column 8, not 16.]

How do I get the right parenthesis to indent at column 8 while keeping the expression indented?

Edit: Updated picture with full expression.

Comment: Settings: indent 4, tab size 4, continuation indent 8.

Comment: It would have been good to see the entire snippet with the conditions.

Comment: @nullpointer Updated image per your request.

Comment: To correctly indent you can move the closing bracket `)` to a previous line itself. *Tip -To use wrapping by IDE. Just try removing the class's closing brace and put it back.(Formats the code with your indentation style.)

Comment: @nullpointer Hmmm.  That doesn't work, because the formatter moves the curly brace to the same line as the paren.

Comment: Well not sure what is the expected behavior here. But if it is to attain the indentation with the settings you've specified. The `?` and `:` are also indented incorrectly, seems like the continuation is indented 12. So what I would suggest is just code the entire `if` in a single line first and then try out the tip I suggested. That should indent all properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136873/discussion-between-bamapookie-and-nullpointer).

Comment: @BamaPookie - the chat is no longer available. Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Joe I have opened a bug for this here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175560

Comment: @BamaPookie - Thanks, I added my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Opened a ticket, and it looks like it was fixed.  See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175560